# as3corelib JSON parsing problem

Tags: json, actionscript, flexbuilder, flash-builder

I have the following two routines in Flash Builder:

```
public function getData():void {

    httpService = new HTTPService();
    httpService.url = "https://mongolab.com/api/1/databases/xxx/collections/system.users/?apiKey=xxx";
    httpService.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT;
    httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
    httpService.send();
}

public function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {

    var rawData:String = String(event.result);
    var arr:Array = JSON.decode(rawData) as Array;
    Debug.log(rawData);
    Debug.log(arr);

    httpService.removeEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
}
```

rawData is displayed as JSON data but arr is displayed as [object Object] rather than an array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
var jsonStr:String = '{"glossary": {"title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {"title": "S"},"GlossSee": "markup"}}';
```

will be parsed and JSON.decode returns an Object and you can access the attributes like this:

```
var obj:* = JSON.decode(jsonStr);
trace(obj.glossary);
```

this

```
var jsonStr:String = '[{"title":"asd"},{"title":"asd"},{"title":"asd"},{"title":"asd"}]';
```

will be parsed and returns an Array (which if you trace it, will return [object Object]).

so if you don't know what data is returned you could just check if

```
var result:* = JSON.decode(jsonStr);
if (result.length != undefined) {
  // array
  var arr:Array = result as Array;
}
else {
  // object
  var obj:Object = result as Object;
}
```

a try/catch around decode would also be good, because you don't know if the jsonStr is well-formed...

cheers

Comment: Thanks mate. Sorry about the delayed response.

Comment: if this is the correct answer for you, pls mark it as that. thx